# Conceptual Doubt About Equations

Tags: linear-algebra

I was solving a simple equation and reached following:

```
-12y = 13y.
```

At this stage, why cant I just divide the whole equation by y? Will this be wrong?

I know that the correct solution is to rephrase as 0 = 25y and conclude that y = 0.
But why is dividing by y wrong?

Comment: You can divide as long as $y$ is not zero. But in this case it is !

Answer (score 2):

If we could divide the equation
$$
-12\,y=13\,y\tag{1}
$$
by $y$, then we would conclude that $-12=13$ which is impossible. This tells us that dividing (1) by $y$ is impossible.

However, this does not mean that we cannot solve (1) for $y$. To do so, add $12\,y$ to both sides of (1) to obtain
$$
0=25\,y\tag{2}
$$
Then divide both sides of (2) by $25$ to obtain
$$
0=y
$$
which explains why dividing by $y$ in the first place gave an absurd answer.